# How do I check if a user can write on a friends wall?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I want to know up front whether I will be able to write on a wall of a user's friend using the Php library.

Currently, I check to see if the Php call throws an exception (due to the user disabling wall, etc) to know if it succeeded but I was wondering if there is anyway to check up front without trying to post on the wall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how
`https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT can_post FROM user WHERE uid=FriendId&access_token=ValidUserAccessToken`

See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/ for more information